# PosgreSQL: I get unexpected results when casting strings as timestamp without time zone for changing time date

Tags: string, postgresql, casting, dst

Server information

show timezone;

> Europe/Paris

I used to cast character strings in timestamp without time zone using:

select '2003-04-30 02:01:47'::timestamp

> 2003-04-30 02:01:47

Generally CAST works well, but I had recently discovered that PostgreSQL doesn't render the expected values in some specifics cases. Indeed for each summer time changing day in France and for the time between 2 and 3 AM PostgreSQL looks like to change strings to local time and not UTC as for the other dates !!

select '2003-03-30 02:01:47'::timestamp

> 2003-03-30 03:01:47

Any explanation and How to get the timestamp as expected (without changing server configuration) ?

Comment: strange indeed but only for timestamp with time zone in my case : SELECT '2003-03-30 02:59:59'::timestamp with time zone < '2003-03-30 03:00:00'::timestamp with time zone is FALSE, which seems wrong

Comment: In my case SELECT '2003-03-30 02:59:59'::timestamp and SELECT '2003-03-30 02:59:59'::timestamptz return the same result > 2003-03-30 03:59:59, that's the point !!

Comment: I can't reproduce that.  What version?

Comment: PostgreSQL 12.8 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 8.4.1 20200928 (Red Hat 8.4.1-1), 64-bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this issue is not related to Postgresql. I use dbeaver as client to communicate with Posgresql. To solve the problem I have to disable data/time formatting in dbeaver options:

[image]

look at this [issue](https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/10896).

and particulary this [comment](https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/10896#issuecomment-756779543).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In the case of timestamp without time zone, I cannot explain your behavior because this does not happen on my side.

In the case of timestamp with time zone, the story is more complex : between 02:00:00 and 02:59:59, the system converts the string into timestamp while increasing the offset by 1 because of the switch from winter time to summer time and increasing the time by 1 hour because 02:00:00+01 (winter time) = 03:00:00+02 (summer time).

The issue is that at 03:00:00 the conversion doesn't increase the time by 1 anymore in order to implement the fact that we lost 1 hour of time due to the switch.

As a result, the string '03:00:00' is converted into the timestamp '03:00:00+02' which is 59 minutes 59 seconds before the timestamp '03:59:59+02' converted from the string '02:59:59'. The conversions of both strings '03:00:00' and '02:59:59" are inconsistent from a timeline perspective.

I raised a bug on that point suggesting to forbid the conversion of strings between '2003-03-30 02:00:00' and '2003-03-30 02:59:59' with an explicit message saying that the corresponding interval of time has never existed due to the winter time / summer time switch.

[Here](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/17244-bda5a623ad3ca0ca@postgresql.org) is the bug report with the answer from Tom Lane

[Here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datetime-invalid-input.html) is the related documentation